# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS High CPU Usage and Running SLow

Tags: 18.04, ssd, cpu, toshiba-satellite

I have a Toshiba Satellite C855d-C5110

- **CPU**: AMD:A6
- **RAM**: 8GB
- **HardDrive**: A brand new SAMSUNG 860 EVO Series 2.5" 250GB SATA III 3D NAND Internal Solid State Drive (SSD)

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS because I thought it was going to run smoothly, but I was wrong!

I looked at the System Monitor and it shows:

```
CPU1: 98% - 100%   CPU2: 40% - 90%
```

I can barely surf the web. I have not installed anything in it yet.

Is it time to let go of my old laptop? or should Ubuntu be performing fine with a AMD A6?

[image: top]
[image: htop]

Comment: What's using so much cpu? Is it at idle, constantly for minutes, or are you running web browsers & stuff? `top` / `htop` should have more info (and can copy & paste text from them). I remember a xapian package used to hog the cpu for minutes every boot until I removed it

Comment: Here are the two commands:TOP https://i.stack.imgur.com/09oJb.png and HTOP https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKUyk.png

Comment: It just froze/crashed too

Comment: Did you read the output? The culprit is pretty obvious on the htop picture. Look at the top three resource hogs...

Comment: It looks like Firefox may be a problem. Quit Firefox, wait 30 seconds, restart Firefox, and monitor top/htop. Also, have you installed any GNOME extensions? Check https://extensions.gnome.org/local/, and turn off all extensions and see if that makes any difference. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: Firefox extensions sometimes tax the cpu a lot too...

Comment: I installed lxde and it is working super fast now! But, I want to use regular ubuntu, lxde is a little bit plain lol.. I will try to turn off GNOME extensions for regular ubuntu

Comment: Here is The System monitor from lxde https://imgur.com/qp87DXL

Comment: what is the cpu usage with gnome without open firefox and with lxde + firefox ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please format your post in a proper way - use plain text instead of images!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test with a lightweight DE like lxde or xfce by tapping in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install lxde
sudo apt install xfce4
```

reboot your computer and at the login screen change to lxde/xfce
[image]

Comment: How do you figure that gnome shell is using too much cpu? And how would a different DE fix that?

Comment: @Catching-Packet did just changing to XFCE/XFWM cause Firefox to use a lot less cpu? With the same number of loaded tabs? (Just closing almost all browser tabs might lower cpu usage a lot)

Comment: i remember when i was installing a distro with kde plasma and it was using the cpu to much, with lxde and the cpu usage was 4%. I didn't notice the cpu usage of firefox when i was writting the answer, and now i realize there's probably another reason...